# GNU Assembler .long Declaration Zeroed Out

Tags: assembly, gcc, gnu-assembler, 68000, objcopy

When assembling code with GNU Binutils declarations such as:

```
.long MY_Label
.long MY_Second_label
```

Assemble without errors but consistently map to zeroed out 32-bit strings when doing a hex dump even when opcodes and other information separate them in the address space. I'm compiling with:

```
m68k-elf-gcc -c hello.s -o rom.o -nostdlib -static && m68k-elf-objcopy -O binary rom.o rom.bin
```

And dumping my binary with:

```
m68k-elf-objdump -D -m m68k --start-address=0x0000 --prefix-addresses -l -x -b binary --disassemble-zeroes rom.bin
```

What am I missing in my assembly code?

Comment: Are they still zero if you link the object file and dump the result of that? How about when your code uses them at runtime?

Comment: Linking was my mistake! I'm cross compiling for a different architecture so I wanted to catch as many errors as I could before testing this code. As you might guess the target system runs without an OS. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never linked your `.o` relocatable so the addresses are still placeholders.  `-c` tells GCC not to link, just assemble, so `-static` and `-nostdlib` are meaningless.

If you use `objdump -drwC rom.o` you'll see the symbol relocations next to the disassembly (`-r` option).

Remove the `-c` from the initial command and keep everything else the same:

```
m68k-elf-gcc  hello.s -o rom.elf  -nostdlib -static
```

Comment: (This question is probably a duplicate, at least if we include the same mistake for x86 or ARM, maybe not m68k.  I was feeling lazy and didn't check.  If anyone finds a duplicate, let me know and I can close the question.)

Comment: Thank you @Peter Cordes. If this was a duplicate I'm sorry - perhaps the way I was phrasing my search was part of the issue in me finding any existing answers. In any case thank you for helping me along. I will try to pay your kindness forward.